# how to draw a straight line using python(without using javascript)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to know that: draw a line without using javascript. 
Need to draw a straight line using python only.
Please give any links for to learn to draw line using python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eh? Because you said, javascript? You need aresult rendered in a browser? Or some GUI-solutions, too?

Comment: @John Barça sry unexpectly its happened...

Comment: @PythonTeam. No worries. Thanks for putting it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't stated your environment, but you can use TkInter if you are doing GUI work with Python. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm 
Note there are a huge number of Python GUI choices, but TkInter is the official Python one: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming
If you are in a web environment, then my advice would be to stick with javascript and the canvas tag.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use [turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#module-turtle) to draw anything you want in python. As the [turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#module-turtle) webpage says, "it uses tkinter for the underlying graphics"